# How to set struts form bean property without submitting the form

Tags: java, javascript, struts-1

I want to set the form bean property without submitting the form.

Suppose, i have the following code in html form :

```
<html:checkbox property="allowUsertoChange"/> <span onClick="toggleAllowChangeCheckbox();">
```

Now property in form bean is :

```
private boolean allowUserstoChange;
```

Is there any way to do this .

Comment: Please answer this question i am stuck of this ...

Comment: can i do this with dwr (direct web remoting) ..